# Re-entering schengen countries

Tags: visas, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I have been to Schengen between 10/05/16 and 23/06/16 (45 days).  Now I wish to go back for 90 days.
Do I have to wait for the beginning of new 180 days period? Or can I enter Schengen about 40 days before the end of the first one (let's say beginning of October) and then stay for 90 days? Can I go between 1/10/16-1/1/16?

I mean that way I would never overstayed in the last 180 days because every time a new day of my new staying is added,  an old one is expired of the 180.

Is there any official representative I could email to have an official answer?

Comment: As for an official representative, they would prefer you save everyone's time by using the official calculator, mentioned in the accepted answer to the linked duplicate.  The URL is http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a "new 180-day period" -- *every* sequence of 180 consecutive days counts. In order to stay 90 days in a row, you need to have been *outside* the Schengen area for all the 90 days immediately before you enter -- this is necessary to follow the rule for the 180-day period that has your 90-day stay as its last half, and periods earlier than that will then automatically follow the rule too.

You can use the official [Schengen calculator](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/schengen_calculator_en.html) to verify this.

Comment: Im sorry for repeating in my own words. But...  As long as Ive been out of schengen for more than 90 days,  I can go back in for 90 days.  Is that right?

Comment: @Sagi: Correct.

Comment: @Sagi yes. If you've been out for 90 days or more before the date of entry then you can enter for 90 days. If you've been out for 89 days or fewer then the maximum duration of your stay depends on the details of your travel history.

Comment: The question was marked duplicate, but this answer is still great. Consider adding it to the canonical.

Comment: @GayotFow I believe moderators are able to move answers around like that, which would, I presume, preserve the answer's votes.